# Error while running react-native-app-auth in react-native 0.60

Tags: react-native

So, I used react-native init [project-name] to create one react-native project. It installed the latest version of native, 0.60. Then I installed react-native-app-auth.

After than I started the metro server using react-native start.
But when I ran react-native run-android, the compiler gave me some errors.

> Task :react-native-app-auth:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.

I've tried to link it manually using react-native link react-native-app-auth.

Don't have any code. It's just some simple configuration.

I expect it to run smoothly, without any errors.

I am getting error after running react-native run-android
https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/4555dc94f460681aaf051c2a3852effa

Answer (score 0):

You can try to jetify the node_modules until `react-native-app-auth` updates his repository making it compatible with RN 0.60.

```
1) npm install --save-dev jetifier
2) npx jetify
3) npx react-native run-android
4) npx jetify
```

as said in: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2019/07/03/version-60#androidx-support

Comment: I installed jetifier and ran the commands you specified, but it still gives me same error.

Comment: build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/e46aa0b31756eaf05e407b5b15a66bcf

Comment: app/build.gradle: https://gist.github.com/ElavanResu/6cc138371b3470aba22dfb9fe433dda2

Comment: It's now working with RN 0.61.2, I am using react-native-app-auth: 4.0.0